# Multiple grouping with checkbox gives a stackoverflow exception

Tags: c#, wpf

I've developed an application which display a list of soccer fixtures grouped by Country and League.
The fixtures are displayed within a `DataGrid` which have the following structure:

```
<UserControl x:Class="MyApp.Controls.FixtureGrid"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="450" d:DesignWidth="800">

    <UserControl.Resources>
        <CollectionViewSource Source="{Binding Fixtures, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" x:Key="GroupedItems">
            <CollectionViewSource.GroupDescriptions>
                <PropertyGroupDescription PropertyName="Country" />
                <PropertyGroupDescription PropertyName="League" />
            </CollectionViewSource.GroupDescriptions>
        </CollectionViewSource>
    </UserControl.Resources>

    <Grid>
        <DataGrid Name="Fixtures" 
                  ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource GroupedItems}}" 
                  AutoGenerateColumns="False"
                  EnableRowVirtualization="True"
                  CanUserAddRows="False"
                  IsReadOnly="True"
                  CanUserSortColumns="True"
                  SelectionMode="Single"
                  VirtualizingPanel.IsVirtualizingWhenGrouping="True">
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTemplateColumn>
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding IsSelected, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                                      />
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Data" Binding="{Binding Kickoff}" />
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Casa" Binding="{Binding Home.Name}" />
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Ospite" Binding="{Binding Away.Name}" />
            </DataGrid.Columns>

            <DataGrid.GroupStyle>
                <GroupStyle>
                    <GroupStyle.ContainerStyle>
                        <Style TargetType="{x:Type GroupItem}">
                            <Setter Property="Template">
                                <Setter.Value>
                                    <ControlTemplate>
                                        <Expander IsExpanded="True"
                                                  Background="#f4f4f4">
                                            <Expander.Header>
                                                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Height="22">

                                                    <CheckBox Name="Country"
                                                              Margin="0 0 10 0"
                                                              IsChecked="{Binding Name.IsSelected, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" 
                                                              Checked="HandleGroupChecking"
                                                              Unchecked="HandleGroupChecking"/>

                                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name.Name}" 
                                                               Margin="5 0 0 0"
                                                               FontWeight="Bold"
                                                               Foreground="Black" 
                                                               FontSize="22"
                                                               VerticalAlignment="Center" />
                                                </StackPanel>
                                            </Expander.Header>
                                            <ItemsPresenter />
                                        </Expander>
                                    </ControlTemplate>
                                </Setter.Value>
                            </Setter>
                        </Style>
                    </GroupStyle.ContainerStyle>
                </GroupStyle>

                <!-- League Group Style -->
                <GroupStyle>
                    <GroupStyle.ContainerStyle>
                        <Style TargetType="{x:Type GroupItem}">
                            <Setter Property="Template">
                                <Setter.Value>
                                    <ControlTemplate>
                                        <Expander IsExpanded="True" 
                                                  Background="#4F4F4F">
                                            <Expander.Header>
                                                <DockPanel Height="16.5" 
                                                           Background="#4F4F4F">

                                                    <CheckBox Name="League"
                                                              Margin="0 0 10 0"
                                                              IsChecked="{Binding Name.IsSelected, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" 
                                                              Checked="HandleGroupChecking"
                                                              Unchecked="HandleGroupChecking"/>

                                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name.Name}" 
                                                               FontWeight="Bold"
                                                               Foreground="White"
                                                               FontSize="11.5"
                                                               VerticalAlignment="Bottom" />
                                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding ItemCount}"
                                                               FontSize="11.5"
                                                               Foreground="Orange" 
                                                               FontWeight="Bold"
                                                               FontStyle="Italic" 
                                                               Margin="10,0,0,0"
                                                               VerticalAlignment="Bottom" />
                                                    <TextBlock FontSize="11.5" 
                                                               Foreground="White"
                                                               FontStyle="Italic" 
                                                               FontWeight="Bold" 
                                                               VerticalAlignment="Bottom" >
                                                        <TextBlock.Style>
                                                            <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
                                                                <Setter Property="Text" Value=" Partite"/>
                                                                <Style.Triggers>
                                                                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ItemCount}" Value="1">
                                                                        <Setter Property="Text" Value=" Partita"/>
                                                                    </DataTrigger>
                                                                </Style.Triggers>
                                                            </Style>
                                                        </TextBlock.Style>
                                                    </TextBlock>
                                                </DockPanel>
                                            </Expander.Header>
                                            <Border Background="{DynamicResource MaterialDesignPaper}">
                                                <ItemsPresenter />
                                            </Border>
                                        </Expander>
                                    </ControlTemplate>
                                </Setter.Value>
                            </Setter>
                        </Style>
                    </GroupStyle.ContainerStyle>
                </GroupStyle>
            </DataGrid.GroupStyle>
        </DataGrid>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

[image: Example of the DataGrid]

As you can see, each fixture have a `CheckBox`, and this checkbox is also available on the League and Country `GroupItem`.

When a `CheckBox` is checked, the following property is fired:

```
<CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding IsSelected, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
```

this property actually contains this logic:

```
public bool IsSelected
{
    get { return _isSelected; }
    set
    {
        _isSelected = value;

        // Check if all the fixtures associated to the country and league have been selected
        bool isAllSelected = FixtureGrid.fvm.Fixtures
            .Where(x => x.Country.Name == _country.Name && x.League.Name == _league.Name)
            .All(x => x.IsSelected == value);

        // Select or deselect the country associated to that matches
        _country.IsSelected = isAllSelected;

        // Same as country
        _league.IsSelected = isAllSelected;

        NotifyPropertyChanged();
    }
}
```

So far all good, when I select all the fixtures, the `CheckBox` available on the Country and League `GroupItem`s is selected automatically. The problem's start when I check a Country or a League, infact the Country and League `CheckBox` have two different properties, like:

**Country Model**

```
public bool IsSelected
{
    get { return _isSelected; }
    set
    {
        _isSelected = value;

       // Check if all the fixtures associated to the country and league 
       bool isAllCountrySelected = FixtureGrid.fvm.Fixtures
            .Where(x => x.Country.Name == _country.Name)
            .All(x => x.IsSelected == value);

       // Select or deselect the country associated to that matches
       _country.IsSelected = isAllCountrySelected;

       bool isAllLeagueSelected = FixtureGrid.fvm.Fixtures
            .Where(x => x.League.Name == _league.Name)
            .All(x => x.IsSelected == value);

        _league.IsSelected = isAllLeagueSelected;

        NotifyPropertyChanged();
    }
}
```

When the property `IsSelected` of country change, I set all the League `CheckBox`es as checked, and the same for the fixtures, but with this, I'm running in a `Stackoverflow` exception 'cause League and Fixture model have the same logic.

**League Model**

```
public bool IsSelected
{
    get { return _isSelected; }
    set
    {
        _isSelected = value;

        // Select all the fixtures associated with that league
        FixtureGrid.fvm.Fixtures
            .Where(x => x.League.Name == _name)
            .Select(x => { x.IsSelected = value; return x; })
            .ToList();

        NotifyPropertyChanged();
    }
}
```

I know that this issue is kinda hard to explain and to fix, so I have prepare a demo application that replicate the issue. You can download the app [here](https://mega.nz/file/VoJyGJ7D#_W1rX6hnlYV1VWxmlxgRQiCc1-ahy6zK_Glm4ck2a6k).

Notice that I have commented the code inside Country and League model to let you test the normal behavior.

How can I prevent the `Stackoverflow` exception?

**UPDATE**

Thanks for the help of Peter I was able to follow his hint, so I changed the `Fixture` model as follows:

```
public bool IsSelected
{
    get { return _isSelected; }
    set
    {
        UpdateField(ref _isSelected, value, OnIsSelectedChanged);
    }
}

private void OnIsSelectedChanged(bool newValue)
{
    bool isAllSelected = FixtureGrid.fvm.Fixtures
        .Where(x => x.Country.Name == _country.Name)
        .All(x => x.IsSelected == newValue);

    _country.IsSelected = isAllSelected;
    _league.IsSelected = isAllSelected;
}

protected void UpdateField<T>(ref T field, T newValue,
Action<T> onChangedCallback = null,
[CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
{
    if (EqualityComparer<T>.Default.Equals(field, newValue))
    {
        return;
    }

    T oldValue = field;

    field = newValue;
    onChangedCallback?.Invoke(newValue);
    PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
}
```

then, I did the same for League model:

```
private bool _isSelected = false;
public bool IsSelected
{
    get { return _isSelected; }
    set
    {
        UpdateField(ref _isSelected, value, OnIsSelectedChanged);
    }
}

private void OnIsSelectedChanged(bool newValue)
{
    FixtureGrid.fvm.Fixtures
                .Where(x => x.League.Name == _name)
                .Select(x => { x.IsSelected = newValue; return x; })
                .ToList();
}


protected void UpdateField<T>(ref T field, T newValue,
Action<T> onChangedCallback = null,
[CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
{
    if (EqualityComparer<T>.Default.Equals(field, newValue))
    {
        return;
    }

    T oldValue = field;

    field = newValue;
    onChangedCallback?.Invoke(newValue);
    PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
}
```

now the problem is this:

When I select all the fixtures of a League and Country, both League and Country are correctly selected, but when I uncheck a fixture, then a Stackoverflow exception is raised on the Fixture model, in particular on this line:

```
_country.IsSelected = isAllSelected;
```

This happen only when I uncheck a fixture

Seems that the code that cause the issue is this:

```
 FixtureGrid.fvm.Fixtures
               .Where(x => x.Country.Name == _name)
               .Select(x => { x.IsSelected = newValue; return x; })
               .ToList();
```

which is inside of Country and League model

Comment: it appears to me that in your country model, in the `IsSelected` setter, when you do `_country.IsSelected = isAllCountrySelected;` you're recursivelly calling it again, until you throw a SO exception.

Comment: @Magnetron exactly, could you suggest me a solution for this?

Comment: Should `.Select(x => { x.IsSelected = value; return x; })` really be assigning again?

Comment: @Deolus The behavior that I'm trying to achieve is the following: if I select a `Country`, then all the fixtures and the leagues of that country must be selected. If I select a `League`, then all the fixtures of that league must be selected. Same for fixtures...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have prepare a demo application that replicate the issue. You can download the app here.

That's not how Stack Overflow works. A question is expected to be 100% self-contained. You may offer external links for *optional* elaboration, but the question should contain a proper [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), and you can't expect anyone to spend time navigating to other sources, never mind downloading entire projects.

That said, typically this problem doesn't come up when `INotifyPropertyChanged` is implemented correctly, because a correct implementation won't do any work when the value isn't changing. For example, here's a typical base class implementation I often use:

```cs
class NotifyPropertyChangedBase : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected void UpdateField<T>(ref T field, T newValue,
        Action<T> onChangedCallback = null,
        [CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        if (EqualityComparer<T>.Default.Equals(field, newValue))
        {
            return;
        }

        T oldValue = field;

        field = newValue;
        onChangedCallback?.Invoke(oldValue);
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

This offers two important features:

1. There is a callback parameter that can be used by the caller to trigger additional logic, should the property change, and…
2. Nothing at all happens if the value being set is the same as the current value.

Using this implementation, your code would change to something like this:

```cs
public bool IsSelected
{
    get { return _isSelected; }
    set { UpdateField(ref _isSelected, value, OnIsSelectedChanged); }
}

private void OnIsSelectedChanged(bool oldIsSelected)
{
    // Check if all the fixtures associated to the country and league have been selected
    bool isAllSelected = FixtureGrid.fvm.Fixtures
        .Where(x => x.Country.Name == _country.Name && x.League.Name == _league.Name)
        .All(x => x.IsSelected == value);

    // Select or deselect the country associated to that matches
    _country.IsSelected = isAllSelected;

    // Same as country
    _league.IsSelected = isAllSelected;
}
```

The first time the property is set, the new value will be different and the `OnIsSelectedChanged()` method will be called. But when the same `County` object's `IsSelected` property is set by `_country.IsSelected = isAllSelected;`, the setter will call `UpdateField()`, which will find the value is already set as needed, and will skip all the other logic (i.e. won't call the callback that gets called when the property changes).

You didn't provide a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) in your question, so I haven't actually tested these proposed changes. But if you do it this way, the recursive issue should go away.

Comment: Hi thanks for your answer and for your time, and excuse me if I didn't provide enough informations to make things easier for you, but I am grateful for taking the time to answer me. I've update my question because I tried your hint, when I check a fixture there aren't problems, but when I uncheck it a stackoverflow exception is raised, could you take a look? Thanks again

Comment: Without a proper [mcve] it is a challenge to identify exactly the problem. But looking at the code that was shared, it seems likely that it's due to the circular relationship between `Fixture` and `League`. The original issue is easily solved, because the basic logic was sound and the code was simply trying to repeat itself. But now you have a new problem, in which the intermediate states your objects wind up in result in a toggling of state that has no resolution, i.e. goes on forever. That part will require rethinking the design. It should be posted as a new question rather than ...

Comment: ... changing your current question to ask about a different problem, and in the new question, please make sure you read and follow the advice in [mcve], and also in [ask]. Don't post code that's not **absolutely necessary** to reproduce the problem, but **do** make sure that the code you post is _everything_, i.e. can be compiled and run without any further additions or changes.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is when you change a property on A which first an event handler that changes a property on B which fires and event handler on which changes a property on A, hence an infinite recursion causing a stack overflow.

Peter shows an eloquent [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64826886/624988) when `INotifyPropertyChanged` is implemented. I use a less eloquent and less verbose solution when the interface is not implemented, for example in Classic Windows Forms.

Simply use a locally boolean field to keep track if you are programmatically changing the property programmatically and if so exit. If not set the field to track that you are changing it programmatically, then change the property. Finally, set the field back to false once the change completes.

```
private bool isChanging;
private void OnIsSelectedChanged(bool newValue)
{
    if (isChanging) return;
    isChanging = true;

    FixtureGrid.fvm.Fixtures
                .Where(x => x.League.Name == _name)
                .Select(x => { x.IsSelected = newValue; return x; })
                .ToList();

    isChanging = false;
}
```